# Turn off double line breaks after usings

Tags: c#, resharper, stylecop

When I reorder my usings with ALT + ENTER, in some cases Resharper (with StyleCop Extension) is adding some additional line breaks between the usings.

How do I turn that off? It started after installing the stylecop Extension, but I cannot find any setting to turn it off. Does anyone know, where I can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resharper, you can turn that formating style off pretty easily.

Options / Code Editing / C# / Formating Style / Blank Lines

and turn the option after using.

Like shown here:
[image of the resharper setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/islDi.png)